# docker ldap request error

Tags: node.js, angular, ldap, entity-relationship

I want to use `ldapjs` within docker and I am getting always following error after I sent a request but I don't understand how can I fix this issue?:

> GET /loginRouter/loginLDAP/id=adfasdfgq9FgasdfChNasdfd4ik/ok ->
>   http://localhost:3100  events.js:160       throw er; //
>   Unhandled 'error' event      ^ Error:
>   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND malibu malibu:389    at errnoException
>   (dns.js:28:10)    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as
>   oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)

My `proxyconf` within `Angular2` looks like:

```
    "/loginLDAP/*": {
    "target": "ldap://malibu:389",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"    
  }
```